# Marker not displaying on GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

I am trying to add multiple markers on `GoogleMap`. This is what I am doing:

```
private void initilizeMap() {
        try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                if (googleMap != null)
                    addMarkers();
                // Getting LocationManager object from System Service
                // LOCATION_SERVICE
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                // Getting the name of the best provider
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        true);

                // Getting Current Location
                Location location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                locationManager
                        .requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Following function adds markers:

```
private void addMarkers() {
        try {
            for (String title : locations.keySet()) {
                if (locations.get(title).getLatitude() != 0
                        && locations.get(title).getLongitude() != 0) {
                    // create marker
                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(locations.get(title).getLatitude(),
                                    locations.get(title).getLongitude()))
                            .title(title);
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_map));
                    // adding marker
                    googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But markers are not displaying, though they are adding up on GoogleMap which I checked while debugging. No exception coming as well. I tried to change the icon image, still not working.

Comment: Are you sure, your latitude/longitude values are inside the expected area? If you used the old maps API previously, also note that LatLng now takes double values, and no longer int-values (which were multiplied by 1,000000 compared to the double values expected now.)

Comment: @user2808624 : Correct !! Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably using the old int values for latitude/longitude as they where expected for the GeoPoint of the previous GoogleMaps API. These are 1 million times too big for the new LatLng object, which expects double values rather than integers.